# Bash Script: Replace values from one file to another

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have one file (`one.cnf`) as:

```
KEY1="value1"
KEY4="VALUE4"
```

And another file (`two.cnf`) as:

```
USER_HOST="local"
KEY1="abc"
PASS="lorem"
KEY2="ABC"
KEY4="XYZ"
```

I want to read the value for the corresponding variables from `one.cnf` and replace in `two.cnf`.
So that the final `two.cnf` looks like

```
USER_HOST="local"
KEY1="value1"
PASS="lorem"
KEY2="ABC"
KEY4="VALUE4"
```

Comment: Are you sourcing these files in a shell script?  In that case, then just source `two.cnf` before `one.cnf`.

Answer (score 6):

With `awk`: read in keys from file one, then replace in file two:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}
     NR==FNR {key[$1]=$2 ; next }
     $1 in key {$2=key[$1]}
     1' one.cnf two.cnf
```

For replacing, use `sponge`

```
awk '<code>' one.cnf two.cnf | sponge two.cnf
```

Alternatively GNU `awk`'s inplace, but this needs a slight code change to ensure `one.cnf` is not emptied:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}
     NR==FNR {key[$1]=$2}
     FNR!=NR && $1 in key {$2=key[$1]}
     1' one.cnf two.cnf
```

Use `-i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bup` for having the original file with `.bup`-suffix as backup.

Comment: Can `tee` be used instead of `sponge`? I think `sponge` is not available by default in MacOs.

Comment: @MagePsycho `tee` would overwrite the file so that is is empty. Simply use a temporary file: `awk '..code..' one.cnf two.cnf > temp.cnf && mv temp.cnf two.cnf`. After all `sponge` doesn't really do much more than that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you there isn't a slash `/` character in your key of value in file one, here's one simple way to do that.

```
while IFS="=" read key value; do sed -i "s/^${key}=.*/${key}=${value}/" two.cnf ; done < one.cnf
```

One of the problems here is that it will change the file even if the values for some keys are identical in both files. If you want to avoid changing the file for keys that don't need to be changed, you can just add a simple grep:

```
while IFS="=" read key value; do grep -xq "${key}=${value}" two.cnf || sed -i "s/^${key}=.*/${key}=${value}/" two.cnf ; done < one.cnf
```

Or without grep and a single sed command:

```
while IFS="=" read key value; do sed -i "/^${key}=/{/^${key}=${value}$/! s/^${key}=.*/${key}=${value}/}" two.cnf ; done < one.cnf
```

Other things to notice:

- If the key from the first file doesn't exist in the second one, it won't be added.
- I assume the first file ONLY includes line in the form of key=value, and no other types of lines.
- Also I suggest to backup the second file before the operation in case anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash           
for val in cat one.cnf          
do       
    KEY=`echo $val | cut -d'=' -f1`     
    VALUE=`echo $val | cut -d'=' -f2`    
    EXISTS=`grep -i "$KEY" two.cnf | grep -v grep`     
    if [ -n "$EXISTS" ]; then       
        VALUE2=`echo "$EXISTS" | cut -d'=' -f2`     
        echo "$VALUE-$VALUE2"                
        sed -i 's/'$VALUE2'/'$VALUE'/g' two.cnf     
    fi      
done
```

change the file path according to your location.

Comment: It is working .i have highlighted the code.